# Can I export a report design layout from Access?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access, report

I'm converting an application from access to c#. I have a adp file for the access application. I've only been able to export the report as a .cls file, which does nothing for me. Is there a way to export the report design view so that I don't have to redo it from scratch??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to use the SaveAsText method to export your report e.g:

```
saveastext(acReport,"ReportName","FileName.txt")
```

And then re-import the report using the LoadFromText method e.g:

```
loadfromtext(acReport,"ReportName","FileName.txt")
```

This approach allows to export elements from MS Access to a text file containing all the file attributes etc and then allows you to load it back in keeping all it's settings/configurations

Comment: And, can I use loadfromtext in c#?

Comment: I've only used it in VB to be honest, not sure how compatible it is with C# but just am aware that it's another method of exporting the MS Access objects.